# Creating keystore BKS for https android connection

Tags: android, security, ssl, bouncycastle, keystore

I found [tutorial](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html) which describes how create and use keystore for https connection. But I have very noob question: where should i put this code to create keystore? at the openssl command promt or in keytool key prompt.

```
    export CLASSPATH=bcprov-jdk16-145.jar
CERTSTORE=res/raw/mystore.bks
if [ -a $CERTSTORE ]; then
    rm $CERTSTORE || exit 1
fi
keytool \
      -import \
      -v \
      -trustcacerts \
      -alias 0 \
      -file <(openssl x509 -in mycert.pem) \
      -keystore $CERTSTORE \
      -storetype BKS \
      -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
      -providerpath /usr/share/java/bcprov.jar \
      -storepass some-password
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither. The code you have pasted is a bash script. Typically you would name this file **make-keystore.sh**. Add this as a first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Make sure it can execute on your linux box

```
chmod +x
```

and run it like

```
./make-keystore.sh
```