# Adding trusted SSL Certificate to an app designed for API 8

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, android-2.2-froyo

I would like to use SSL for connections between my android app and the server hosting my web services.

I wanted to used a self-signed certificate and then use `SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`

but then there would be a vulnerability to man-in-the-middle attacks, so I decided to use trusted certificates.

I am going to buy a certificate, but I wanted to know which CAs are the most trusted and how to generate a BKS

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065379/how-to-create-a-bks-bouncycastle-format-java-keystore-that-contains-a-client-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382342/creating-keystore-bks-for-https-android-connection) and opted for the the solution described in the first link, namely generating it with the bouncy castle library and loading it as a raw resource in the app. Is it a safe method, and will it work safely with devices using android 2.2 ?

I'm trying to learn how all of this work, but it's my first experience using certificates.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-signed certificate is not inherently vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attacks. Using the `ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` is though, so you shouldn't use it. As long as you properly set up your app to trust your self-signed certificate, and verify its validity properly there is really no security problem.

If you want to buy a certificate, just get one from a CA that comes bundled with Android 2.2, and you won't have to deal with custom trust stores and extra code: it will just work, because the system trusts the issuing CA.